# Does mSubscription.unsubscribe onCreate work the same as onDestroy in an Activity?

Tags: java, android, rx-java, unsubscribe

1. Will rxjava mSubscription.unsubscribe onCreate work the same way as onDestroy in an Activity?
2. Will it work the same way and unsubscribe to prevent memory leak by placing it in onCreate as `subscription.subscribeOn().observeOn().subscribe().unsubscribe`
   because the Activity is constantly being called to populate the next fragment and pop back to stack. if mSubscription.unsubscribe is done in onDestroy in the Activity, it gives a a RunTimeException: Unable to destroy activity because of NullPointerException
3. Am I missing out some life cycle issue here?

Thank you!

```
    private ViewPager viewPager;
    private TabLayout tabLayout;
    private int mPosition;
    private String id;
    private Subscription mSubscription;
    private Context mContext;
    private RealmResults<Experience> realmResults; 
    private String animateExtraColumnName, tag;
    private Boolean automaticUpdate, animateResults;


    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_employment);

        User currentUser = AppDelegate.getCurrentUser();
        assert currentUser != null;
        mEmployee = getRealm().where(Employee.class).equalTo("user.id", currentUser.getId()).findFirst();


            //Server returns Experience's ID
            if (employeeExperience == null) {

                AccessToken accessToken = currentUser.getAccessTokenAsTokenType(AppDelegate.getContext(), "Bearer");
               employeeExperienceAPIOAuth2Call apiCall = new employeeExperienceAPIOAuth2Call(AppDelegate.getContext(), accessToken);

                Observable<ResponseEmployeeExperience> postEmployeeExperienceObservable = apiCall.postEmployeeExperiencesRX();

                mSubscription = postEmployeeExperienceObservable
                        .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                        .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                        .subscribe((data) -> {
                            Log.d(TAG, "onCreate: Subscribe ");
                         employeeExperience = data.getEmployeeExperience();
                            Log.d(TAG, "onCreate: employeeExperience.getId()");

                            getRealm().beginTransaction();
                            getRealm().copyToRealmOrUpdate(employeeExperience);
                            // This adds the new employeeExperience object into the EmployeeExperiences RealmList
                            employee.employeeExperiences.add(employeeExperience);
                            getRealm().commitTransaction();
                            getRealm().close();

                            //unsubscribe here because the activity doesnt close itself to begin with?
                            mSubscription.unsubscribe();
                            Log.d(TAG, "onCreate: Unsubscribe: ");

                            // prepare data needed by our fragment
                            FragmentAddOrUpdateEmploymentHistory addEmploymentHistoryFragment = new FragmentAddOrUpdateEmploymentHistory();

                            FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
                            fm.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.edit_frame_layout, addEmploymentHistoryFragment, "EDIT_FRAGMENT").commit();

                        }, (error) -> {
                            // TODO do whatever error handling we need to do here
                            Log.d(TAG, "onCreate: postEmployeeExp error");
                            error.printStackTrace();
                        });
            }

        } else if (employee.getEmployeeExperiences() != null) {
            employeeExperience = getRealm().where(employeeExperience.class).equalTo("id", id).findFirst();

            FragmentAddOrUpdateEmploymentHistory addEmploymentHistoryFragment = new FragmentAddOrUpdateEmploymentHistory();

            FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
            fm.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.edit_frame_layout, addEmploymentHistoryFragment, "EDIT_FRAGMENT").commit();
        }

        ImageButton checkButton = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.edit_toolbar_check);
        checkButton.setOnClickListener(this);

        ImageButton crossButton = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.edit_toolbar_cross);
        crossButton.setOnClickListener(this);

    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {

        Fragment editFragments = getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("EDIT_FRAGMENT");

        switch (view.getId()) {

            case R.id.edit_toolbar_check:
                if (editFragments instanceof FragmentEditDate) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "onClick: editdate ");
                    getSupportFragmentManager().popBackStack();
                } else if (editFragments instanceof FragmentSalary){
                    Log.d(TAG, "onClick: salary ");
                    getSupportFragmentManager().popBackStack();
                } else if (editFragments instanceof FragmentAddOrUpdateEmploymentHistory) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "onClick: employmenthistory ");
                    finish();
                } else if (editFragments instanceof FragmentSingleChoice) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "singlechoice  " );
                    getSupportFragmentManager().popBackStack();
                }
                else if (editFragments instanceof FragmentMultipleChoice) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "multiplechoice  " );
                    getSupportFragmentManager().popBackStack();
                }
                break;


            case R.id.edit_toolbar_cross:
                if (editFragments instanceof FragmentAddOrUpdateEmploymentHistory) {

                            getRealm().beginTransaction();
                            employeeExperience.DELETE();
                            getRealm().commitTransaction();
                            getRealm().close();
                        }
                        finish();
                    } else {
                        finish();

                    }
                } else {
                    getSupportFragmentManager().popBackStack(); }
                break;

        }
    }
```

Comment: why don't you call unsubscribe in the onComplete()?

Comment: where should this onComplete() be?

Comment: inside your subscribe method

Answer (score 0):

In short - once you subscribe to an `Observable` you're ready to receive and react to notifications from it (`onNext`, `onError`, `onComplete`). Also in most of the cases (for cold Observables) this is actually the triggering point for an `Observable` to start emitting items.

`Unsubscribing` from an Observable means you're no longer interested in receiving any further notifications. You need to `unsubscribe` when you no longer want to receive anything, similarly to how you can release any resources in Activity's `onDestroy()` method. Of course the parallel with the activity's lifecycle is just for comparison - the subscribing / unsubscribing process is completely separate thing.

You can read in details about what `subscribing` and `unsubscribing` means [HERE][1] [1]: http://reactivex.io/documentation/contract.html

That said, few concrete suggestions for your code:

You're currently performing too much stuff on Android's main thread. I suggest to move all real-related stuff as part of the RX chain, instead in the `onNext()` handler in `subscribe(...)`. This way it's gonna be performed on an `io` thread. Something like:

```
...
mSubscription = postEmployeeExperienceObservable
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .doOnNext(data -> saveDataToRealm(data))
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribe((data) -> {
                // prepare data needed by our fragment
                FragmentAddOrUpdateEmploymentHistory addEmploymentHistoryFragment = new FragmentAddOrUpdateEmploymentHistory();

                FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
                fm.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.edit_frame_layout, addEmploymentHistoryFragment, "EDIT_FRAGMENT").commit();

            }, (error) -> {
                // TODO do whatever error handling we need to do here
                Log.d(TAG, "onCreate: postEmployeeExp error");
                error.printStackTrace();
            });
}

private Data saveDataToRealm(Data data) {
    employeeExperience = data.getEmployeeExperience();
    Log.d(TAG, "onCreate: employeeExperience.getId()");

    getRealm().beginTransaction();
    getRealm().copyToRealmOrUpdate(employeeExperience);
    // This adds the new employeeExperience object into the EmployeeExperiences RealmList
    employee.employeeExperiences.add(employeeExperience);
    getRealm().commitTransaction();
    getRealm().close();
}
```

As far as unsubscribing is concerned - if you really want to `unsubscribe` from within the `onNext()` event, a better strategy is to subscribe via a `Subscriber<Data>` and then just use it's `unsubscribe()` method. In other words - you won't be calling `mSubscription.unsubscribe()` but instead `this.unsubscribe()`.

```
mSubscription = postEmployeeExperienceObservable
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .doOnNext(data -> saveDataToRealm(data))
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribe(new Subscriber<Data>() {

                @Override
                public void onCompleted() {

                }

                @Override
                public void onError(Throwable e) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onNext(Data data) {
                    ...
                    this.unsubscribe();
                }
            });
```

All that said, I don't think you really need to `unsubscribe` from the `onNext()` method in your case, instead you can just do so in `onDestroy()`, checking if a subscription was previously created of course:

```
@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    if (mSubscription != null) {
        mSubscription.unsubscribe();
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for your feedback! i was missing out null checker for my subscription in onDestroy